Does description need to be next to the noun when using a comma?
I'm confused as to whether the participial clause (in this case "enhancing the portfolio's value") needs to be placed next to what it describes (in this case "the two"). So my question is, which is grammatically correct?
(If both are grammatically correct, then I prefer #1.)

The two offer distinct backgrounds and networks, enhancing the portfolio's value.
Enhancing the portfolio's value, the two offer distinct backgrounds and networks.


Your sentence is not clear at all. How does offering distinct backgrounds and networks enhance a portfolio's value?   How does offering a moon roof enhance a car's value?

Both are grammatical. But the structure and meaning is different.
(1) means "The two offer distinct backgrounds and networks, which enhances the portfolio's value." Here, what enhances the portfolio's value is the fact that the two offer distinct backgrounds and networks.
(2) means "Since they enhance the portfolio's value, the two offer distinct backgrounds and networks." Here, what enhances the portfolio's value is "the two".
Which you should use depends on prior context and/or what you intend to say.

Agreed. It's the verb offer that enhancing enhances in #1.

... Yes; a paraphrase of #1 is 'The two offer distinct backgrounds and networks, and this enhances the portfolio's value.' I'd add that this is probably the more felicitous reading (ie I'd choose it, though both are grammatical).

Closely related: Can a participle phrase modify a clause? [But note that 'participle/participial phrase' is really contrary to modern analysis).
